# Template class with variable array size: initialize with array reference or brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization

Consider the following class:

```
template <size_t nb_rows, size_t nb_cols>
class ButtonMatrix
{
  public:
    ButtonMatrix(const pin_t (&rowPins)[nb_rows], const pin_t (&colPins)[nb_cols], const uint8_t (&addresses)[nb_rows][nb_cols])
      : rowPins(rowPins), colPins(colPins), addresses(addresses) { }
  private:
    const pin_t (&rowPins)[nb_rows], (&colPins)[nb_cols];
    const uint8_t (&addresses)[nb_rows][nb_cols];
};
```

I can initialize it using arrays like this:

```
const pin_t rows[2] = {0, 1};
const pin_t cols[2] = {2, 3};

const uint8_t addresses[2][2] = {
  {0x01, 0x02},
  {0x03, 0x04}
};

ButtonMatrix<2, 2> bm(rows, cols, addresses);
```

And it works just fine. However, I'd like to be able to initialize it using brace-enclosed initializer lists as well:

```
ButtonMatrix<2, 2> bm({0, 1}, {2, 3}, addresses);
```

It compiles without problems, but it obviously doesn't work, because the `rowPins` and `colPins` only live for the duration of the constructor, and cannot be used in the other methods of the class.
To get around this, I could copy the contents of `rowPins` and `colPins`:

```
template <size_t nb_rows, size_t nb_cols>
class ButtonMatrix
{
  public:
    ButtonMatrix(const pin_t (&rowPins)[nb_rows], const pin_t (&colPins)[nb_cols], const uint8_t (&addresses)[nb_rows][nb_cols])
      : addresses(addresses) {
      memcpy(this->rowPins, rowPins, sizeof(rowPins[0]) * nb_rows);
      memcpy(this->colPins, colPins, sizeof(colPins[0]) * nb_cols);
    }
  private:
    pin_t rowPins[nb_rows], colPins[nb_cols];
    const uint8_t (&addresses)[nb_rows][nb_cols];
};
```

This way, I can either initialize it with array reference or with brace-enclosed initializer list.
The only drawback is that when using array references, there's two copies of the same data. The target platform is Arduino, so I'd like to keep memory usage to a minimum.
Is there a way to determine whether an initializer list was used to initialize it, and if so, dynamically memory for the array?
Something along these lines: [C++ overload constructor with const array and initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772095/c-overload-constructor-with-const-array-and-initializer-list)

It would be nice to have compile-time errors if the dimensions of the initializer lists don't match `nb_rows` and `nb_cols`, so that rules out `std::initializer_list` (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: rows and cols you provide to ButtonMatrix are values or a reference? I think this could clarify yourself which way is the right one to follow.

Comment: `addresses` being multidimensional severely complicates dynamic allocation. Can this be a flat array of size `nb_rows * nb_cols` instead?

Comment: How do you plan to dispose of `rowPins` and `colPins` if you do allocate the memory dynamically?

Comment: @GiuseppePuoti : if I use the first way of initialization (using arrays), they are references to these global arrays, and if I use a brace-enclosed initializer list, they are values that are used to initialize two temporary arrays, which rowPins and colPins are references to. The latter option would require to copy these two temporary arrays.

Comment: @cdhowie : I could probably live with that. However, it would be easier to use if it's a real 2D matrix.

Comment: @tttapa See my updated answer, using `std::array`.

Comment: @n.m. `rowPins` and `colPins` would be pointers (`const pin_t*`), and I would have two other pointers `rowPinsStorage` and `colPinsStorage`. If a reference to an array is used in the constructor, `rowPins` points to this array. If an initializer list is used, I dynamically allocate memory for the array using `malloc`, and `rowPinsStorage` points to this memory. Then I  copy the values from the initializer list / temporary array to this memory, and assign `rowPinsStorage` to `rowPins`.
Then in the destructor, I free `rowPinsStorage`.
Please see the link in my OP for details.

Comment: @tttapa Don't use `malloc()` in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can replace naked arrays with `std::array` (they are much easier to dynamically allocate for multidimensional arrays), a partial solution is to rely on the fact that temporaries prefer to be passed as rvalue references:

```
template <typename T>
void no_deleter(T*) { }

template <typename T>
void default_deleter(T *p) {
    delete p;
}

template <size_t nb_rows, size_t nb_cols>
class ButtonMatrix
{
  public:
    using row_array_t = std::array<pin_t, nb_rows>;
    using col_array_t = std::array<pin_t, nb_cols>;
    using address_array_t = std::array<std::array<uint8_t, nb_cols>, nb_rows>;

  private:
    template <typename T>
    using array_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, void (*)(T*)>;

  public:
    ButtonMatrix(const row_array_t &rowPins, const col_array_t &colPins, const address_array_t &addresses)
      : rowPins(&rowPins, no_deleter<const row_array_t>),
        colPins(&colPins, no_deleter<const col_array_t>),
        addresses(&addresses, no_deleter<const address_array_t>) { }

    ButtonMatrix(row_array_t &&rowPins, col_array_t &&colPins, address_array_t &&addresses)
      : rowPins(new row_array_t(std::move(rowPins)), default_deleter<const row_array_t>),
        colPins(new col_array_t(std::move(colPins)), default_deleter<const col_array_t>),
        addresses(new address_array_t(std::move(addresses)), default_deleter<const address_array_t>) { }

  private:
    array_ptr<const row_array_t> rowPins;
    array_ptr<const col_array_t> colPins;
    array_ptr<const address_array_t> addresses;
};
```

Now, when you do this, the passed static arrays get stored by pointer and won't be deleted:

```
ButtonMatrix<2, 2>::row_array_t rows{{0, 1}};
ButtonMatrix<2, 2>::col_array_t cols{{2, 3}};

ButtonMatrix<2, 2>::address_array_t addresses = {{
  {{0x01, 0x02}},
  {{0x03, 0x04}}
}};

ButtonMatrix<2, 2> bm(rows, cols, addresses);
```

But, if you pass everything inline, a copy gets made into a heap-allocated array, which *does* get deleted properly:

```
ButtonMatrix<2, 2> bm2({{0, 1}}, {{2, 3}}, {{{{1, 2}}, {{3, 4}}}});
```

(Note you need double braces on everything because of the way the `std::array` constructor works.)

---

This is all a bit dangerous though, since **temporaries can also bind to a const reference** -- if you mix static and temporary data in the same constructor call, the first constructor will be called and **you'll store a pointer to a temporary that's going away**.  Not good.

<sup>A better solution (allowing both static and temporary data in the same constructor invocation) will require a lot of template magic.  I may try to come up with this, but I may not have time.</sup>

Even though it's a bit more verbose, I would go with a solution where you specify *at the call site* whether the argument must be copied.  It will be much safer, and much easier to prove that you aren't storing long-lived pointers to temporaries.

Comment: If memory is at a premium, you might also consider defining a nested class `ButtonMatrix<m,n>::Data` to hold the three `std::array` members and put one `std::unique_ptr<Data, void(*)(Data*)>` in `ButtonMatrix`, so that a `ButtonMatrix` object contains just one object pointer and one function pointer, rather than three object pointers and three function pointers.

Comment: @aschepler Right. This solution was designed with the idea that some arrays might be dynamically allocated and others not. I haven't implemented that possibility in the constructor, but wanted to leave the data member detail of that solution finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very interesting (and a lot to take in). However, I don't know if it's feasible on an Arduino. There's no support for std::array or std::unique_ptr, for example.

Comment: @tttapa It's not too hard to write similar templates, just enough to get this working.